# KALI Linux 4 LXDE virtual box Error

Tags: virtualbox, kali-linux, kernel, lxde, guest-additions

I Installed Kali Linux 4 LXDE on Virtual Box and installed the *Guest Additions CD Image*. But I get the error

> modprobe vboxsf failed

I tried `apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`,
but `apt` can't find it in the repositories.

```
linux-headers-$(uname -r) ==> linux-headers-4.18.0-kali2-amd64
```

This is my sources.list:

```
 deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

and my other config parameters:

- virtual box version => 6 ,
- host OS => linux mint 19 tara ,
- virtualbox-guest-x11  ==> installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For first, update:

```
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y upgrade
sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade
reboot
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

If still not found, manually search linux headers

```
sudo apt-cache search linux-headers
```

and install (for example if you find linux-headers-4.9.0-kali4-amd64):

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-4.9.0-kali4-amd64
reboot
```